# Single URL Rewrite rule to remove shebang and force HTTPS in IIS

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have a URL like so:
`demo.url.com/folder/folder2/#!/param1/param2`

I'm trying to force HTTPS which I have done successfully, however when I attempt to use regex rule to also remove the #!, I get an error in the redirect.

This is what I currently have:

```
    <match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+\#!.*" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://demo.url.com/{URL}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do a redirect based on the hash string. Browser doesn't transmit the part after hash to the server.

It's called [Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and is client side only. That means that you will not be able to see this part on server side

Comment: You're absolutely right! Back to the drawing board. Thanks!